# ねぇ、ちゃっと寄ってかない! Is the sentence written correctly?

Tags: syntax

I mistakenly typed the statement with a question mark. It was actually written with an exclamation point. ねぇ、ちゃっと寄ってかない! I am thinking that the phrase should be ended with a ka or no, and be phrased as a question. Apparently, the sentence can be written both as a statement and as a question.

Comment: 「かない」ですか「こない」ですか。「こない」でしょう。

Comment: Neither か nor の are necessary as question markers; the sentence alone could be a question clearly enough, depending on the tone of voice.  If a marker is preferred, either could work, depending on the speaker, audience, and intended nuance.

Comment: @A.Ellett 寄ってかない？ is a colloquial contraction of 寄っていかない？

Comment: Jack, your initial question used a question mark in the quote, and all of the comments, and Chocolate's answer, responded to this form.  You have since edited to change the quote to use an exclamation point instead.  What was the reason for this?  Was the Japanese sentence actually _not_ a question, and instead an exclamatory statement?  If so, then **no, generally neither か nor の would be appropriate at the end of an exclamatory statement.**  But please clarify!

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi, please reflect with the exclamation point.

Comment: 「ねぇ、ちゃっと寄ってかない！」, with an 「！」 not 「？」,  would mean the same thing... It can't be interpreted as anything other than an invitation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ねぇ、ちゃっと寄ってかない？ Is the sentence written correctly?

If you mean "just a little" "just a moment" or "for a little while" by the ちゃっと, then it should be a typo for ちょっと, as in: ねぇ、ちょっと寄ってかない？

If you mean "a chat room" by the ちゃっと, then it's *usually* written in Katanaka, as in: ねぇ、チャット(に)寄ってかない？

> Should this phrase be ended with ka or no, as a question?

No, as pointed out in the comments, you don't need a か or の in a question, especially in casual conversation.

寄ってかないか？ would make sense too. It would sound masculine and maybe a bit blunt.

寄ってかないの？ has a nuance that the speaker is/was expecting the hearer to drop by somewhere, like "Oh, so you won't drop by (although I thought you would)?"